# how can I stop bootstrap panels going full width at the 1200px breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created three panels that sit horizontally in a row inside a fluid container each with col-lg-4 classes, however, when i reduce the browser size to below 1200px, they stack on top of each other and expand to full browser width. I want the panels to expand to full width at around a 900px breakpoint, not 1200px.

Here is an example of what the panels in the webpage look like above 1200px browser width:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVi6L.png

and here is an example of what the panels in the webpage look like below 1200px browser width:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAfUB.png

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid trse-feature">
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default panelL"> 
            <div class="panel-body icon">
                <h2 class="text-center">We also work in conjuction with</h2>
            </div> <!-- end panel-body --> 
        </div> <!-- end panel -->
    </div> <!-- end col-lg-4 --> 

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default panelM">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="https://www.trsengineering.co.uk/" target="_blank"><img src="trsenone.png" class="img-responsive"></a>

            </div> <!-- end panel body -->
        </div> <!-- end panel --> 
    </div> <!-- end col-lg-4 -->



<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default panelR">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p class="text-center trse-p"> TRSE is a certified Notification Body (NoBo) and all TMD maintenance proposals are business cased to demonstrate the benefits from an optimised, improved and Engineering Accepted maintenance regime. </span></p>
        </div> <!-- end panel-body --> 
    </div> <!-- end panel -->
</div> <!-- end col-lg-4 -->
```

I think it is something to do with altering the bootstrap breakpoints like so:

@media (max-width: 1200px) {}

but i'm not entirely sure what to implement.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using `container-fluid`, how about just `container` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. This is working correctly:

```html
<div class="container-fluid trse-feature">
          <div class="row"> 
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="panel panel-default panelL"> 
                      <div class="panel-body icon">
                          <h2 class="text-center">We also work in conjuction with</h2>
                      </div> <!-- end panel-body --> 
                  </div> <!-- end panel -->
              </div> <!-- end col-lg-4 --> 
          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="panel panel-default panelM">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <a href="https://www.trsengineering.co.uk/" target="_blank"><img src="trsenone.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
          
                      </div> <!-- end panel body -->
                  </div> <!-- end panel --> 
              </div> <!-- end col-lg-4 -->
          
          
          
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="panel panel-default panelR">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      <p class="text-center trse-p"> TRSE is a certified Notification Body (NoBo) and all TMD maintenance proposals are business cased to demonstrate the benefits from an optimised, improved and Engineering Accepted maintenance regime. </span></p>
                  </div> <!-- end panel-body --> 
              </div> <!-- end panel -->
          </div> <!-- end col-lg-4 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

> col-lg-4

**to**

> col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4

This is basically giving support to all devices (Desktop/ipads/ mobile).

You can also change the breakpoints of these divs.
**lg is for bigger screens.**

**md for laptop and small screens.**

**sm is for ipads.**

**xs is for mobile .**

Bootstrap is a 12 column grid system so here 4+4+4 = 12 makes the logic.

In your case you were only using col-lg-4 class which is written only for big desktop screens and after 1200px the css was not working.

> You can also use just col-sm-4 if you want to just minimize the
>   things.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `md` breakpoint instead which stacks at 992px.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default panelL"> 
            <div class="panel-body icon">
                <h2 class="text-center">We also work in conjuction with</h2>
            </div> <!-- end panel-body --> 
        </div> <!-- end panel -->
    </div>
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/KeLX4nQ1vs

- `col-xs-4` will not stack vertically
- `col-sm-4` will stack at 768px
- `col-md-4` will stack at 992px
- `col-lg-4` will stack at 1200px

[Breakpoints and the Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Answer (score 0):

For `col-lg-x` the breakpoint is at 1200px, for `col-md-x` is at 992px, for `col-sm-x` at 768px and if you use `col-xs-x`, the columns never collapse. You can use `col-md-` instead of `col-lg-` and edit the breakpoint in the css from 992px to 900px if 992px is not ok.

Or you can define your own media query and your own class for this.